# how to update items in an array/list with mongo c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

With the recent update to [10gen c# driver for mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial) I want to update my code so it use the strongly typed version.

My previous call was :

```
var update2 = new UpdateBuilder();
var index = album.Ratings.IndexOf(rating);
update2.Set("Ratings." + index + ".Number", number);
update2.Set("Rating", album.Rating);
_session.Db().GetCollection<Album>("Album")
    .Update(Query<Album>.Where(x => x.Id == objId), update2); //this line is working
```

The new call would be :

```
update.Set(x => x.Ratings[index].Number, number);
//update2.Set("Ratings." + index + ".Number", number); previous call
```

But I get this exception :

> Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
>   (Album x) =>
>   x.Ratings.get_Item(WebApp.Areas.API.Controllers.RatingController+<>c__DisplayClass5.index).Number.

Is there any way I can update an item inside a List?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting problem.  This works when using a constant like below:

```
var update = Update<Album>.Set(x => x.Ratings[0].Number, 10);
```

However, this apparently breaks when you use a variable, like you have done with index.  This is definitely a bug.  I have created a Jira issue for it here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-598.

This is most likely due to us not partially evaluating the expression before processing it.

Comment: Thanks Craig, something that would also be realy nice is when when call _session.Db().GetCollection<Advertisement>("Advertisement") if we did not have to write "Advertisement" and that it takes by default the name of the class so we would not have magic string in the app! It's some very nice work that have been done in mongo-LINQ!

Comment: That is an on-going debate.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-126.  For now, most people write an extension method that uses typeof(T).Name for the collection name.